# How to using Docker environmental variables in NextJS13 client side with minimal production deployment by using standalone?

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js, docker-compose, environment-variables

### Goal

I want to pass an environmental variable from docker-compose to my NextJS app and use in it in a component on the client-side. When I try to do so however, it returns as undefined. The first split second before the component is fully mounted, the variable contains the correct content so I know it's not the Docker settings being faulty.

### Question

How can I use Docker environmental variables in the NextJS13 client side with my current production build settings (minimal production deployment by using standalone)?

### What I've tried so far

1. using NEXT_PUBLIC tag for the variable name as mentioned by the  [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables)
2. adding the variable to `.env.local` first. This will just overwrite it with the content of `.env.local`

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM node:16-stretch-slim AS runner
ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/.next/static ./.next/static
COPY --from=builder /app/.next/standalone ./

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

#### next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
    output: 'standalone',
    productionBrowserSourceMaps: true,
}


module.exports = nextConfig
```

#### docker-compose

```
    version: '3'
    services:
      web:
        image: next-js
        build: .
        container_name: next-js-container
        ports:
          - "8000:3000"
        environment:
          - NEXT_PUBLIC_VAR=fromdocker
```

#### Component in which I want to use the variable

```
import * as React from "react";

export type ComponentProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

export const Component: React.FC<ComponentProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return <div>{process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VAR}</div>;
};
```